# Login com facebook api não retorna o email do usuário

Tags: php, facebook, login

Saudações galera,

Passei horas e mais horas pesquisando alguma solução pra esse problema, inclusive aqui no site, mas não achei algo que me ajudasse.

Estou implementando um cadastro de um site pelo facebook usando a api do facebook diretamente. Consigo realizar a conexão, faço a solicitação de permissão do usuário e tenho os dados do usuário em retorno. O problema é que só vem o nome e o id do usuário, mesmo eu passando no scope que quero as informações de e-mail e perfil público.
Estou rodando essa programação localmente em um servidor apache pelo Xampp, será que pode ser esse o problema?
Fiz essa programação diretamente no php e também por javascript e em ambas a situação é a mesma.

Desde já agradeço a colaboração.

Segue o código usado (mesmo disponível nos exemplos do facebook):

Opa, o código que estou usando pra testar é o mesmo disponível nos exemplos do face:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.init({
    appId      : 1644402569130903,
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                    // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.4' // use version 2.2
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
});

};

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
        // document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        //   'into this app.';
        FB.login(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    } else {
         // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
         // they are logged into this app or not.
         // document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
         //   'into Facebook.';
         FB.login(function(response) {
             console.log(response);
         });
     }
}

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    console.log(response);
    // Aqui ele loga no console a resposta vinda do facebook, mas vem apenas o ID e Nome do usuário..
});


}
```

**Testei num servidor na nuvem e com outros usuário além do meu, e mesmo assim recebo apenas o nome e ID do usuário logado.

Comment: Pode postar o código também? As vezes pode ser por estar localhost, tente subir para o servidor e refaça o teste.

Comment: Opa, alterei a pergunta e inclui o código usado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está solicitando permissão de email na hora do login?

```
FB.login( function(response){
    // ...
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Lembrando que se o usuário deixar o e-mail como privado/vazio, não tem como pegar. Ou seja, nem sempre você vai conseguir o e-mail de todos que efetuarem login.

**[update]**
Estava dando uma olhada e vi que agora você precisa especificar o campo que deseja receber, caso contrário é retornado apenas o nome e id.

Exemplo:

```
FB.login(function(){

  FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, email'}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });

}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: Sim, coloquei a solicitação pelo email e perfil publico. 
inclusive na popup que abre solicitando a autorização, ele mostra que o app ta pedindo pra acessar o email e perfil publico

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, deve ser isso.

Comment: Show de bola cara, era isso mesmo.. Muito obrigado.. Eles deveriam deixar essas informações com acesso mais fácil heuheueh