# Api Login do facebook não retorna e-mail mesmo solicitando campo

Tags: login, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Minha api do facebook não está retornando campo e-mail.
Vi em um post do fórum dando a solução para este problema, solicitando o campo na api, porém fiz isso e o mesmo não funciona.

> [Login com facebook api não retorna o email do usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77157/login-com-facebook-api-n%C3%A3o-retorna-o-email-do-usu%C3%A1rio)

Interessante é que quando eu testo local ele da certo, e no ar vem como "undefined" (APENAS CAMPO E-MAIL, TODO RESTANTE RETORNA NORMAL)

No cadastro da api nas configurações do facebook à API já está por padrão solicitando e-mail para usuário

Segue código

```
FB.api('me?fields=email,name,link,picture', function (response) { 
console.log(response)
}):
```

Comment: Cara, teu código não está igual ao do link que tu postou.
Está passando o `scope` no Login? No post o cara passava um segundo parametro que era um objeto com os `fields` ao invés de concatenar na URL... Isso altera o resultado?

Comment: Concatenar não altera o resultado. também não há necessidade do scope no login, tanto como eu disse os outros campos funcionam e local também funciona.
Estranhamente agora está buscando o e-mail, não fez sentido algum. Vou monitorar para saber se vai parar de funcionar!

Comment: [FECHADO]
Realmente fernandosavio, é necessário ter o botão fb.login pois é o scope que cobra permissão de e-mail quando aparece mensagem para usuário permitir o aplicativo do facebook.
Se você não utiliza o scope ele pede a permissão mas somente cobra nome e foto (que é o padrão das aplicações)